# What is the reason of having nanoTime 10 times slower than currentTimeMillis?

Tags: java, nanotime

Consider the following code

```
package tests;

public class Test_computer_speed {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for(int i=0; i<10; ++i) {
            testMillis();
        }

        for(int i=0; i<10; ++i) {
            testNanos();
        }

    }

    public static void testMillis() {


        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis(), endTime = startTime + 6000, iterations = 0, now;
        while (true) {
            now = System.currentTimeMillis();
            if (now > endTime)
                break;
            iterations++;
        }

        System.out.println("In 6 seconds, the loop performed " + iterations + " iterations.");

    }

    public static void testNanos() {


        long startTime = System.nanoTime(), endTime = startTime + 6000000000l, iterations = 0, now;
        while (true) {
            now = System.nanoTime();
            if (now > endTime)
                break;
            iterations++;
        }

        System.out.println("In 6 seconds, the loop performed " + iterations + " iterations.");

    }

}
```

output follows:

```
>java tests.Test_computer_speed
In 6 seconds, the loop performed 1402955969 iterations.
In 6 seconds, the loop performed 1452564156 iterations.
In 6 seconds, the loop performed 1443087123 iterations.
In 6 seconds, the loop performed 1417403052 iterations.
In 6 seconds, the loop performed 1451880195 iterations.
In 6 seconds, the loop performed 1444997459 iterations.
In 6 seconds, the loop performed 1438911291 iterations.
In 6 seconds, the loop performed 1461714025 iterations.
In 6 seconds, the loop performed 1460849690 iterations.
In 6 seconds, the loop performed 1441407031 iterations.
In 6 seconds, the loop performed 512124051 iterations.
In 6 seconds, the loop performed 524528348 iterations.
In 6 seconds, the loop performed 525100685 iterations.
In 6 seconds, the loop performed 528140105 iterations.
In 6 seconds, the loop performed 526142121 iterations.
In 6 seconds, the loop performed 526086430 iterations.
In 6 seconds, the loop performed 530290126 iterations.
In 6 seconds, the loop performed 529469812 iterations.
In 6 seconds, the loop performed 528229751 iterations.
In 6 seconds, the loop performed 529689093 iterations.
```

This means that `nanoTime()` function is 10 times slower, than `currentTimeMillis`.

What is the sense of having more precise function if it is slower?

In other words, Java is cheating, probably gaining precision by waiting for some time on call.

**UPDATE**

Look at uncertainty. The nanoTime() speed is 10 times slower, and the uncertainty is 10 times better.

This means, that absolute uncertainty IS THE SAME.

Comment: 10 times slower?  1441407031/512124051 is approximately 2.8, not 10.  And why is it surprising that more precision requires more work to calculate?

Comment: 1460849690 / 512124051 = 2.8 times slower? Your point still stands that it's slower, but 2.8 is very different from 10.

Comment: I was rounding to the order of magnitude (number of digits)

Comment: @LouisWasserman where do you see more precision? Number of loops is uncertain to the same level

Comment: @Dims I mean that `System.nanoTime()` returns, at least potentially, a more precise value, which may require more work to compute.

Comment: @LouisWasserman imagine you have very precise scalpel, which can cut with nanometer precision; unfortunately, the thickness of this scalpel is 10 millimeters; and you are saying, that it is normal to have more precise scalpel being more thick; I mean that the only use of such scalpel is to use as guillotine; you can't do helpful surgery with it, you can just cu head and be sure, that the length of the remaining neck stump is the precise number of nanometers :)

Comment: @Dims read the duplicate question, which explains the more expensive API required to get more precise results.

Comment: @LouisWasserman the problem is that losses are of the same value as gains; imagine you need to pay 100 dollars to save 10 cents

Comment: `System.currentTimeMillis()` doesn't actually have millisecond precision, though; it's not accurate to the millisecond.  In any event, based on your numbers, `nanoTime()` takes approximately 11 nanoseconds, which is still better resolution than `currentTimeMillis` could possibly provide.

Comment: Your test is invalid. You're measuring `currentTimeMillis()` with millisecond accuracy, but `currentTimeNanos()` with nanosecond accuracy. You're getting a major granularity problem which is skewing your results by up to three orders of magnitude.